# Is it possible to create a section for Language interpretation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Google translate is not good, and there's no forum or Q&A website dedicate for **professional translation**. So is it possible to create a section for that. Where users can post words or small paragraphs, **NOT TEXTS** that they want to translate?

Because if I want to translate a text, I could use Google translate, and if I want a professional translation, I have to hire someone.

Comment: Check out [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).  You can make proposals for new SE sites there and once you have [enough people committed to your new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) the site will be activated automagically :)  There is a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/30/beta) involved in that process too!

Comment: A section where exactly? On every stack exchange site? A new stack exchange site?

Comment: @Oded a section on stackexchange like **ubuntu serverfault SO unix english section**...

Comment: That would be a _new stack exchange_ site. And as @Lix commented, you can make a proposal for one on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Oded yep a new site, i just called it sections because most of the sites here are sub domains, and i am used to call a sub domain, a section

Comment: i have just posted it on [area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/is-it-possible-to-create-a-webstie-for-language-interpretation) thank you

Comment: I don't think you understood what we're trying to tell you. You might want to read the FAQ.

Comment: @Bobby you guys told me to post it on area51 and i did that, what else should i do?

Comment: @Bobby - I think the OP wants to be able to translate text *within* the existing Stack Exchange sites, rather than creating a new site dedicated to translation.

Comment: @Chris read the OP comments - he clearly wants a new site.

Comment: @Eli you posted a discussion while people here advised you to propose new site - see my answer, there is already existing proposal.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - Ah - my mistake,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, what you are after is new StackExchange site focused on professional translation - fair enough.

There is already pending proposal for [languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16613/languages) site which says:

> Proposed Q&A site for anyone learning a new language or wanting to have **a quick translation of a sentence/idea**. This site is focused on people looking for resources to learn new languages, **translating phrases or questions**, as well as grammar related questions.

Sounds very much like what you want, so feel free to commit:

[image: commit screenshot]

And wait patiently until enough users commit as well - you will get email in such case.

If you really insist on having a site only for translation, you can always [propose your own site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=professional) but I won't advice it.

Comment: ok I'll wait for the language site